# Set text in table in similar alignment

Tags: html, css

How I can set text under one aliment:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/

```
..............
        <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>for test one</td>
                    <td>and test second</td>
                    <td>1 test threee</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; test test  four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 2 four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 4 four</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; tests software </td>
                    <td>&bull; software table</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 7 four</td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; test 8 four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 3 four</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>  </td>
                    <td>&bull; test and four</td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
    .........
```

For example I want to set the text around 30% from the left table border.

Comment: The fiddle is empty, just an fyi. Let me know when it's ready, happy to help.

Comment: Can you try now, please?

Answer (score 1):

In a word...padding

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aLjudn8y/)

```css
tr td {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
tr:nth-child(n+3) td {
  padding-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>for test one</td>
    <td>and test second</td>
    <td>1 test threee</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&bull; test test four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 2 four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 4 four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&bull; tests software</td>
    <td>&bull; software table</td>
    <td>&bull; test 7 four</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&bull; test 8 four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 3 four</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>&bull; test and four</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Very good solution but I want to apply this only on the rows with bullets.

Comment: Then adjust as required...be specific in your selectors. https://jsfiddle.net/aLjudn8y/1/

Comment: I tried to use this code but the alignment of the complete code is not very good. Can you see the code from here https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/?

Answer (score 0):

Updated :

```css
table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.textLeft {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

.paddingleft {
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>for test one</td>
    <td>and test second</td>
    <td>1 test threee</td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="firstRow">
    <td>&bull; test test four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 2 four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 4 four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&bull; tests software </td>
    <td>&bull; software table</td>
    <td>&bull; test 7 four</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&bull; test 8 four</td>
    <td>&bull; test 3 four</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>&bull; test and four</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
```

Here is a sample of a combination of helper classes that help align.

Comment: @PeterPenzov please see changes., Depending on the css of the table rows, and table if your using something like bootstrap best to use percent since the majority of it is percent wise.

Comment: I get thus result http://tinypic.com/r/2it32as/9 Is there any other solution for fixed alignment. https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/

Comment: very possible, just depends on the rest of the css. something may be overriding the alignment. Tweaking the percent from left padding is not working with a greater percentage. You could also give a class to the <tr>  the left and different css to the rest of the table rows

Comment: Here is the result when I add the complete code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqrvVE?editors=1100